# When using IIS, Passport js thinks everyone is same user, doesnt route when using reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Having a very confusing issue with passport and our node/express/react application using a domain name we purchased.

On our ip address for the server, we can access the app fine, the post for the /login works, each user gets their own passport session, and can use the logout post fine.

However when we use Microsoft IIS to reverse proxy to http:localhost:3000/ the website will show using the domain, but when we try to login it takes almost 30 seconds before it succeeds, you will have to refresh the page and the user will have their auth and can visit the site. /logout post acts the exact same way. All of the gets work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cache-related issue you could solve the issue by disabling the cache and kernel cache in iis.

1)Open iis manager, select your site.

2)Double click on the output caching from the middle pane.

[image]

3)On the right side under Actions, click on Edit Feature Settings

4)Uncheck Enable Cache and Enable kernel cache

5)Click OK

[image]

You could also disable client cache in iis:

Client Cache